# Is there a solution for the following differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable. Then there exists $y: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that:
$$y'=f(y),\quad y(0)=1$$

Is that statement true? I don't have any idea on how to even approach it.

Comment: [Picard−Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: Standard counter example: $f(y)=y^2$. Or perhaps more familiar, $f(y)=y^2+1$. Or did you mean that an interval $0\in I\subset\Bbb R$ exists with a solution $y:I\to \Bbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have seen the Cauchy-Lipschitz (or Picard-Lindelöf) theorem as mentioned by nejimban, then you should see that as soon as $f$ is $C^1$, it will be locally Lipschitz around $1$ (the initial condition for the solution), which implies that a solution exists on a neighborhood of $0$ -- it will even, in this case, inherit the smoothness of $f$.

However, $f$ might not be **globally** Lipschitz, in the sense that there might not exist a uniform Lipschitz constant $L$ such that $|f(a)-f(b)| \leq L |a-b|$ for **all** $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ (only in a neighborhood of every point). This should hint that a global solution **might not exist**, and the example given above by Lutz Lehmann with $f(y)=y^2$ is probably the simplest example.